# org mode - how to disable some keybindings?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I started using Emacs (currently for org mode only). I don't use priorities in my TODOs, hence I'd like to disable `S-UP` and `S-DOWN` key bindings (which loop through the priorities). How can I do this?

Comment: Here you go:  http://superuser.com/a/828744/206164

Comment: Your answer on Superuser deserves an upvote, but I have only 1 reputation on that site :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@lawlist gave you the recipe in his comment. Here's how to find this out for yourself.

1. See if there is a keymap variable for the mode in question - typically there is one. In this case, try `C-h v org-mode-map`. If you find no such variable, fish around a little, using the apropos commands - for example, `M-x apropos-variable org-mode`.
2. Bind the key(s) in question to `nil` in that keymap:

   ```
   (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "S-<up>") nil)
   ```

---

`C-h m` gives you info about the current mode.  Sometimes it lists the important key bindings for the mode.  And `C-h b` (anywhere) lists lots of key bindings for the current context.

If you want to see *all* of the key bindings that belong to a given keymap variable (in human-readable form), then load library [**`help-fns+.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/help-fns%2b.el) and then use **`C-h M-k`** followed by the keymap variable name (e.g. `org-mode-map`).  See [Help+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HelpPlus).